# Plotting a grid of squares from true/false values in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, loops, for-loop, boolean

I want to create a grid of equal squares in MATLAB. I have a matrix which stores mixed
values of 1 or a 0. I want the 1's to represent black squares and the 0's to be white with a white outline encapsulating the black squares for clearness/black grid lines for white boxes.

I used this thread

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8711971/plotting-a-grid-of-squares-in-matlab
```

however there is no need for units or values on either axis (i'm representing some shaded/unshaded PV panels).

The pseudocode is something like:

```
   For(x row of variable, y column of variable)

     If (variablename(x,y)) value = 1
       draw a black square with white outline

    elseif (variablename(x,y)) value = 0
       draw a white square with black outline
       end
    end
```

Comment: Have a look [here](http://goo.gl/Dy8V89) how to disable axes and labels.

Answer (score 2):

Why not just use:

```
n = 5;
S = round(rand(n));

imagesc(S);
colormap(gray);
grid on;
```

Comment: I could perhaps but to give you an example, my variable typically looks like:

      wallshading = ones(11,6)
      wallshading(1:5) = 0

I then want to map that the way you just did but I need the grid to be the same layout as the array and I need white grid lines around my black boxes and black grind lines around my white boxes to separate them.

Comment: I tried imagesc(wallshading) using my code above. But how can I get white grid lines around each black square and black squares around each white square? I need each square to be 1x1 in dimension with the fill plot the size of the array i.e 11x6 of 1x1 squares.